# RegularExpressionValidator syntax for multiline TextBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a multiline **TextBox** for which any of the following inputs are valid:

1. Empty string (the text can optionally be blank upon submit).
2. A single numeric (0 - 9) string, up to 9 digits long.
3. Multiple numeric strings, each up to 9 digits long, each separated by carriage return (\r) and/or newline (\n).

What regular expression will enable me to validate these criteria, using a **RegularExpressionValidator** control? I'm currently experimenting with the excellent [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) tool, but would appreciate insight in evaluating these multiple criteria efficiently at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:\d{1,9}(?:[\r\n]\d{1,9})*)?$
```